# easier way of doing both portrait and landscape in one xml file? in android

Tags: android

I have nearly finished my app but still have to make sure landscape orientations is ok, is there any xml code that I can put in layout that will cover both portrait and landscape?

Many thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout will work in both orientations. You can specify a layout for landscape orientation by adding an xml with the same name in a folder named `layout-landscape` as per this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Note that you should handle make sure your App works correct when orientation is changed as Android may recreate your view if you do not handle the orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeLayout in your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/boxbig" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <Button  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bottom and Right"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```